# VK_API, PHP, массив из бд

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

```
$notes = $db->query("SELECT note FROM notes WHERE vk_id = $id");
$list = array();
   while($notelist = $notes->fetch()){

   $list[] = $notelist['note'];
}
```

Есть такой код, но проблема, что я глупый человек и данный код не работает. 
Сама задача: я должен получить массив из бд, где содержатся все значения **note** по **WHERE vk_id = $id**
Как я могу это сделать?

Comment: дак вы посмотрите, что у вас получилось в `$notelist` этом. того и гляди что там `[0 => .....]` а не `['note' => ...]` зы: `$list = $notes->fetchAll(DO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);`

Comment: Ничего не понял..

Comment: Посмотрите что содержится в $notelist. `var_dump($notelist);`

Comment: Ну в принципе то да, он просто пустой...